# Put data from my database to my PDF (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, pdf

I am creating a from in C# that will generate a PDF when a student logs in. I am done with the template, my problem is how to put the data on my database to my PDF.

The data that is needed to be present in the PDF is the student's name, student's course, credit units, and all the subjects he/she is enrolled.

all data are stored in the students and enrolled table.
here are the tables:

```
mysql> describe enroll;
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Eid             | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Students_studid | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Subjects_Subjid | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and

```
mysql> describe students;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| studid     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| StudName   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StudCourse | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StudYr     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StudGender | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and here is my generate PDF form:

```
    class Form_PDF : Form {

        public Form_PDF(){
        Text = "PDF";

        CenterToScreen();

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(""+Form_Login.getUser+".pdf", FileMode.Create);

           Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);

           PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);


           document.AddAuthor("The Author");

           document.AddCreator("using iTextSharp");

           document.AddKeywords("C# PDF");

           document.AddSubject("C# PDF");

           document.AddTitle("PDF creation using iTextSharp");


           document.Open();




           PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
           PdfContentByte xy = writer.DirectContent;

           //BaseFont f_cb = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            BaseFont f_cn = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);


           //XY
           xy.BeginText();
           xy.SetFontAndSize(f_cn, 9);

           xy.SetTextMatrix(110, 661); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Student Name: " +Form_Login.getUser);

           xy.SetTextMatrix(110, 637); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Semester: ");



           xy.SetTextMatrix(230, 661); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Course: "); 
            sqlConnection1.Close();

           xy.SetTextMatrix(230, 637); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Section: ");

           xy.SetTextMatrix(230, 613); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Division: ");

           xy.SetTextMatrix(375, 661); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("School Year: ");

           xy.SetTextMatrix(375, 637); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Credit Units: ");

           cb.SetLineWidth(0f);
           cb.MoveTo(100, 601);
           cb.LineTo(510, 601);
           cb.Stroke();

           xy.SetTextMatrix(120, 577); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Subject Code");

           xy.SetTextMatrix(195, 577); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Subject Description");

           xy.SetTextMatrix(310, 577); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Subject Schedule");

           xy.SetTextMatrix(405, 577); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Room #");

           xy.SetTextMatrix(470, 577); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Units");

           cb.SetLineWidth(0f);
           cb.MoveTo(100, 560);
           cb.LineTo(510, 560);
           cb.Stroke();

           xy.SetTextMatrix(120, 313); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("NOTE: Assessment on this Registration Card is TEMPORARY only. Final assessment will be determined by");

           xy.SetTextMatrix(145, 301); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("the Finance office.");

           cb.SetLineWidth(0f);
           cb.MoveTo(400, 253);
           cb.LineTo(510, 253);
           cb.Stroke();

           xy.SetTextMatrix(425, 241); // Left, Top
           xy.ShowText("Registrar Officer");

           int row = 1;
            for (int y = 0; y != 70; y++)
            {
               xy.SetTextMatrix(10, row);
               xy.ShowText("Y: " + row.ToString());
               row += 12; // The spacing between the rows is set to 12 "points"
            }
            int col = 35;
            for (int x = 0; x != 22; x++)
            {
               xy.SetTextMatrix(col, 829);
               xy.ShowText("X: " + col.ToString());
               col += 25; // The spacing between the columns is set to 25 "points"
            }
            xy.EndText();


            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(f_cn, 16);


            //START DIRI
            iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\\Users\\db\\Desktop\\addu-logo.jpg");
            img.SetAbsolutePosition(185, 697);
            img.ScalePercent(10f);
            cb.AddImage(img);


            cb.SetTextMatrix(240, 733); // Left, Top
            cb.ShowText("Ateneo de Davao University");

            cb.SetTextMatrix(280, 718);
            cb.ShowText("Registrar's Office");

            cb.SetTextMatrix(266, 703);
            cb.ShowText("Student Registration");


            cb.EndText();



           //document.Add(new Paragraph("Ateneo de Davao University"));
           document.Close();
           writer.Close();
           fs.Close();



    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I need to insert the course of the student, and the subjects he/she is enrolled in the PDF (how do I do it?)

Comment: Sooo... rephrasing your question, what you want to know is... how to get data from a MySql database in C#?

Answer (score 0):

it is just a Example :

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 

public class Example
{

    static void Main() 
    {
        string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=user12;
            password=34klq*;database=mydb";

        MySqlConnection conn = null;
        MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try 
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            conn.Open();

            string stm = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read()) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetInt32(0) + ": " 
                    + rdr.GetString(1));
            }

        } catch (MySqlException ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",  ex.ToString());

        } finally 
        {
            if (rdr != null) 
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }

            if (conn != null) 
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

for complite information kindly visit

http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/

the data from mysql will come in this

```
while (rdr.Read()) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetInt32(0) + ": " 
                    + rdr.GetString(1));
            }
```

here loop will gives you to record one by one,

change the code

Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetInt32(0) + ": " + rdr.GetString(1));

as you want in your example